# CodeIgniter Routing 404 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and am having trouble figuring out routing. I am getting a 404 page not found error when I go to "/SimplePie1". Is my routing the issue, or have I messed up the controller or view? Thanks.

My controller:

```
class Feeder extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('rss');
        $feed = $this->rss;
        $feed->set_feed_url('http://www.theverge.com/rss/frontpage');
        $success = $feed->init();
        $feed->handle_content_type();

        $this->load->view('feed_view', array('feed' => $feed));
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('navbar.php'); ?>

<?php foreach($feed as $item) : ?>
    <br />
    <a href="<?php echo $item['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $item['title']; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

My routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homeController";
$route['feed_views'] = "SimplePie1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: What happens if you go to /Feeder/index? CI allows the URL to be accessed via controller/function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code means

```
$route['feed_views'] = "SimplePie1";
```

If you have `feed_views` in the `url` then launch the `SimplePie1` controller and by default the `index` method will be invoked, so now the question is : do you have a controller class named `SimplePie1` ? If not then, it should show a`404` not found error.

I think it should be

```
$route['feed_views'] = "Feeder";
```

so, it'll be mapped to the `Feeder/index` (class/method).
Read more on [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. Got my names mixed up copying things around.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Assuming you default controller is feeder , so "/feeder" will load the index function which loads the feed_view without no routes just default controller.

In routes you rewrite controllers and it's methods,Not the views names like you mention in your route.php.

Review [URI Roouting](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)